# Synthesize in latest XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am learning XCode and iOS for the first time.  When creating an outlet with the mouse and Ctrl key, what happens to the @synthesize? In the tutorial I'm watching, it gets autocreated, but I don't see it in my Xcode. I am running the lastest OS X and latest Xcode.

If it's not autocreated, can we still overwrite the getter and setter?

Say something like this:

```
@synthesize topSpeed = _topSpeed;

(void)setTopSpeed:(double)speed
{
    if((speed < 1) && (speed > 0) _topSpeed = speed;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have the latest OS X (!0.8) and Xcode (4.6), you do not need to explicitly specify @synthesize for each property you declare in the @interface — unless you're going to overwrite both setter and getter or if you want to use a different name as highlighted in your example of

```
@synthesize topSpeed = _topSpeed;
```

You can also overwrite the getter, and setter (if the property attribute is not readonly) as your code

```
(void)setTopSpeed:(double)speed
{
    if((speed < 1) && (speed > 0) _topSpeed = speed;
}
```

shown.

Comment: okay, does the latest xcode also add the _ (underscore) now too?

Comment: And it is always a good practice to use `self.topSpeed` instead of `_topSpeed`

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya Not at dealloc.

Comment: +1 to @A-Live. But now in ARC, dealloc of ivars aren't required mostly.

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya You don't have to use ARC yet, I personally like not to.

Comment: @A-Live: My client asks to use ARC, and they are creators. :)